# SQL Server : change PK type from uniqueidentifier to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have designed a database that has primary key type `uniqueidentifier` for all tables. It has 50 tables and existing data. Then, I knew it was a bad idea. I want to change to `int` pk type from `uniqueidentifier`.

How can I do? How do I move the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

The general steps to take are (links are to MSDN information on performing these steps with SQL Server):

1. Delete the current Primary Key constraint - [Delete Primary Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190621.aspx)
2. Alter the table to drop your Unique Identifier field and create a new Integer field - [Alter Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190273.aspx)
3. Create a new Primary Key on the new Integer Field [Create Primary Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189039.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

just done a script, tested on a couple of tables and works fine, test it yourself before you execute it in your production environment.

The Script does the following.

1. Find all the columns where Primary key has data type Uniqueidentifier.
2. Drop the primary key constraint.
3. drop the Uniqueidentifier column.
4. Add INT column with Identity starting with seed value of 1 and increment of 1.
5. Make that column the Primary key column in that table.

---

```
declare @table SYSNAME,@Schema SYSNAME 
      , @PkColumn SYSNAME, @ContName SYSNAME
      ,@Sql nvarchar(max)


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR  
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(O.object_id) AS ConstraintName
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) AS SchemaName
    ,OBJECT_NAME(O.parent_object_id) AS TableName
    ,c.name ColumName
FROM sys.objects o 
inner join sys.columns c ON o.parent_object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types   t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE o.type_desc = 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
and   t.name = 'uniqueidentifier'

Open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @ContName , @Schema , @table, @PkColumn

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

   SET @Sql= 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(@table) 
              + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@ContName)

    Exec sp_executesql @Sql


   SET @Sql= 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(@table) 
              + ' DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(@PkColumn)

   Exec sp_executesql @Sql


   SET @Sql= 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(@table) 
              + ' ADD  ' + QUOTENAME(@PkColumn) 
              + ' INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) '

   Exec sp_executesql @Sql

  SET @Sql= 'ALTER TABLE  ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(@table) 
           + ' ADD CONSTRAINT '+ QUOTENAME(@table+'_'+ @PkColumn)
           + ' PRIMARY KEY ('+QUOTENAME(@PkColumn)+')'

  Exec sp_executesql @Sql

  fetch next from db_cursor into @ContName , @Schema , @table, @PkColumn

END

Close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

Comment: Thank you for doing the script. I have a lot of data. I musn't  delete they. my database has foreign key. How do I move the foreign key?